# ListView clear() clearing every List in the ArrayAdapter

Tags: android, android-listview, android-arrayadapter, notifydatasetchanged

in my custom ArrayAdapter, I am using the view holder pattern, inside the `getView()` method I have a `TextChangedListener()` to which I am doing this:

```
List<Child> children;

@Override
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
  List<Adult> converted  = Converter.convert(children);
  clear();
  addAll(converted);
  notifyDataSetChanged();
}

@Override
public void clear() {
  children.clear();
}

@Override
public void addAll(Collection<? extends Currency> collection) {
  children.addAll(collection);
}
```

I set the children list in the constructor, so please don't worry about that being null or anything, during debug, it has data, the `converted` list has data, the clear method is called and both lists at that point are cleared...could someone shed some light as to why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to just clear a particular list just use

```
converted.clear();
```

or

```
children.clear();
```

Both are getting cleared due to converted being a reference to children. To avoid this you can use

```
List<Adult> converted = new ArrayList<>();
converted.addAll(Converter.convert(children);
```

and continue to call

```
clear();
```

However, it should be noted that when you are calling

```
clear();
```

You are actually calling it on the entire adapter, which clears the dataset. Which is why I said you should specify which list you are trying to clear, but I would also use the ArrayList<>() declaration from above with .addAll()